# Unity shader/ effect that turns inner & lower parts darker

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Is there a Unity shader/ material/ certain effect which would, for any given mesh, automatically turn the more downways parts (relative to world coordinates) as well as the more inwards or concave parts (relative to mesh center) darker (a dark blue tint, to be specific)?

To illustrate with an example, I'm basically looking for something which acts like the highly fluid dark color one can paint over fantasy figurines, which then flows into e.g. the rib cage or the cape, increasing the 3d vividness of the shape. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You are searching for [Ambient Occlusion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-AmbientOcclusion.html)

Comment: Thanks! I've been using it for architecture and whole scenes but never connected its use for smaller structures until after posting, yet it may be perfect for that too, especially if using a very high strength! Small caveat: It has a small issue in VR/ stereo displays. https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/issues/486